# Is there a windows installer (wubi) for Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: windows, 15.04

Is there a windows installer (WUBI) for Ubuntu 15.04? I found one on the installation CD but it says that's its for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted  from https://gameplayjdk.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/ubuntu-the-big-mystery-about-wubi-explained-19-04-2014/

> Canonical has stopped the official support and promotion of wubi for
>   all Ubuntu versions past 12.10. But wubi got shipped until 13.10 on
>   releases.ubuntu.com and is still shipped as part of the .iso images
>   for the future ubuntu releases (verified for 14.04 &<), where it’s
>   functionality is limited to a prompt which tells you to burn the image
>   onto a DVD and restart and boot your PC from CD-Drive.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. There is no wubi in new Ubuntu releases.

If you want to install Ubuntu into Windows, you can use Virtualbox instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever old version of Wubi to install Ubuntu (e.g. 12 or 14), then

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -p
```

(even more times) until you reach the current version.