# Cant find wubi.exe in my files

Tags: wubi, 15.10

I downloaded all the files that came along the iso of ubuntu 15.10 provided on the ubuntu website. But when i copied them to a usb, it shows no signs of the 15.10 installer. PLSSSS help!!!

Comment: Wubi is no longer maintained or recommended, consider a real install or virtual machine.

Comment: You forgot to mention what windows you'd be using wubi on. If that is Windows 8 or newer: wubi does NOT work with those operating systems (due to changes Microsoft made). see http://askubuntu.com/questions/626438/is-there-a-windows-installer-wubi-for-ubuntu-15-04 for instance.

Comment: Community release of 15.10 from hakuna-matata available [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases/tag/1510r299)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need Wubi.exe because ubuntu installer is much easier today , get a flash drive and download this [universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3.exe)

find your linux ISO and burn it to flash drive

**Warning : all your files on that USB will be removed**
restart your Computer then boot to flash drive and finally  follow the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is no longer required. Just make a bootable drive and run it, it should work fine.
I faced a problem myself, so i just used another software to make the bootable drive. It Worked! :)